# meanjs - angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm just learning `mean.js` . Just did the installation steps in http://meanjs.org .
But when loaded in browser, console is showing error `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` . do we need to include `angularjs` separately ?

Comment: Did you execute both `npm install` and `bower install`?

Comment: have you include angular in your html?

Comment: @Charminbear I executed both. But the bower install is returning error 'fatal: unable to connect to github.com:' . So that may be the issue ?

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat No..do we need to include angular separately ???

Comment: May be firewall blocking your access, check this [link](http://www.drawbackz.com/stack/242418/howto-fix-bower-ecmderr.html)

Comment: Edit with a copy of your bower.json please, maybe we can check why you can't connect to the github repository. I'm with @Hareesh, maybe a firewall is the problem

Comment: since you are using meanjs so you don't have to include in html

Answer (score 2):

Use this command

```
bower install --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you dont need to add angularjs one more   time because angularjs is added as default in meanjs project.

You may try:

```
npm install
```

This command will install node packages and bower packages.

And then run project again:

```
npm start
```

Check running meanjs at http://localhost:3000

Hopefully you have a nice time with meanjs.